# In nodejs, how was javascript with c++ code references compiled and executed by the V8 engine?

Tags: node.js, v8

I know that internalBindings is used in nodejs to help javascript code introduce the c++ module, but in the end v8 will compile javascript into ast. At this time, ast contains both the content of the javascript language and the content referenced by c++.

When executing ast, I wonder if it is parsed When reaching the content referenced by c++, first run the c++ code and then return the result, so that JavaScript can be fully integrated into the c++ code. Is this how v8 runs js code?

Comment: Javascript is not fully integrated by c++. Instead javascript objects are (which is trivial to do since javascript objects are implemented in c++ so there's no need to translate anything). It is c++ values (strings, numbers) and data structures (structs, classes) that first need to be converted into javascript objects before returning them to the calling javascript functions and it is the job of the c++ code to do this - node.js and v8 does nothing to help you. The answer is the programmer makes sure that c++ code returns proper javascript objects

Comment: thanks. I have some questions yet. Native module in nodejs, such as fs c++ module will be add javascript global context before node.js run javascript code. Then fs c++ module is binary code. When v8 engine run javascript code, how v8 connect   javascript code with the binary code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Bergi mentioned the nature of native biding is different and it happens at binary "level" in what we call an ABI (Application Binary Interface). Basically it is the runtime that knows how to deal with objects written in both languages because they respect the same binary structure and interface.

NodeJS allows you to write [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) but it typically provides a [Node-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html) interface in C which can be used with a [C++ wrapper](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) that provides a C++ object model and exception handling semantics with low overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> javascript with c++ code references […] v8 will compile javascript into ast. At this time, ast contains both the content of the javascript language and the content referenced by c++.

You are mistaken about the nature of native bindings. There is no JS *code* referencing C++ *code*, and there is no AST that contains code content in both languages. Only JavaScript code is parsed into the AST.

When calling from JS into C++, it is a JS *object* that references a C++ *object* and calls its methods. The internal bindings of nodejs are set up by C++ code, creating JS object that represent native resources and JS function objects that call a C++ function.